# Drop down input element acting strange and not transferring value to "search.php" page

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

New code ive scrapped together. It is still not doing exactly what im looking for. Right now, I have a form that sends a text box and drop down file to my PHP code. The textbox works fine but the drop down doesn't send info over. The array constantly shows only the last result of "WY". Here is my code.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<input name="q" type="text"> 

<select name="states" id="states">
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="NV">NV</option>
<option value="TX">TX</option>
<option value="WY">WY</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$dir = 'folder';
$_GET['states'];
$states = array("CA", "NV", "TX", "WY");
foreach($states as $state);
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtoupper($_GET['q']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir); 
while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) {
if(strpos(strtoupper($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file)) {
    echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>";
}
}

closedir($res);
?>

<?php
echo $htmlHeader;
while($stuff){
echo $stuff;
}
echo "<script>window.location = 
'http://www.example.com/$dir/$state/$q.htm'</script>";
?>
```

Comment: So you want to get the selected on dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

First error I can see is this below 
change

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
```

to

```
 <form action="search.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to loop if you just want to get the value of the selected `<select>` tag you just have to simply get the name.

```
$state = $_GET['states'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue thanks to both of your answers. I appreciate it very much. PHP is difficult but im figuring it out slowly. Check out the site as its updated: http://www.pissedoffdrivers.com